# The use of the phrase 'paradigm shift'

Tags: phrase-usage, ellipsis

Looking at the definition of '[Paradigm Shift](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/paradigm-shift.html)' it seems that we need to *mention* the shift ***...from [something]...to [something]...*** whenever we use the phrase.

My question is whether it is possible to leave the matter **as it is** *(and not mentioning from....to)* using 'paradigm shift'?

Say the context is an email that was once used/or believed to be just a communicating tool for exchanging simple messages/information is now an important medium of marketing. May I simply begin the article with...

> As we witness the paradigm shift in the usage of emails....*blah blah blah...*

Note that I will **not** mention ***'from.... to'*** format opposite to what I observe in most of the sentences where 'paradigm shift' is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already established the context, describing the evolution from simple informative messages to annoying spam  ;-), then you can put a label on that process and refer to it as a 'paradigm shift'. But it would not be a good idea to "begin the article" by talking about "the" paradigm shift or even "a" paradigm shift, if you don't immediately go on to say what you have in mind. People will understand only that some kind of major shift is involved; but beyond that, they will be in the dark. Why would you expect them to be already on your wavelength, and thinking in terms of short informational texts versus marketing emails?